# Problema con Subconsultas SQL

Tags: pandas, sql, subconsultas

Esta es mi primera pregunta en el foro. Tengo una tabla llamada datos_5minutos que se carga usando el pandas data-reader. Tiene los siguientes campos: **ID, TIKER, DATE, CLOSE, VOLUME**

El problema es que debo hacer una consulta que me agrupe por **TIKER** y me arroje:

- El primer valor **CLOSE** as ***OPEN***
- El maxiomo valor **CLOSE** as ***HIGH***
- El minimo valor **CLOSE** as ***LOW***
- El ultimo valor **CLOSE** as ***CLOSE***
- El ultimo valor **VOLUME** as ***VOLUME***

Esto es lo que tenemos hasta ahora:

```
SELECT tiker, min(datex), max(datex), min(close), max(close)
    FROM datos_5minutos
    GROUP BY datos_5minutos.tiker
ORDER BY datex;
```

pero me falta el ***OPEN***, el ***CLOSE*** y el ***VOLUME***.

Puedo sacarlos haciendo:

```
SELECT close as OPEN
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;

SELECT close as CLOSE, VOLUME
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

pero tengo que sacar **todo en una sola consulta**.

Alguna ayuda por allí?

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Me parece entender que te refieres a algo así:

```
SELECT c1.*,d1.VOLUME mindate_vol,d2.VOLUME maxdate_vol FROM (
    SELECT TIKER,CLOSE,MAX(DATEX) maxdate,MIN(DATEX) mindate
      FROM datos_5minutos GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c1 JOIN datos_5minutos d1
  ON c1.TIKER=d1.TIKER AND c1.CLOSE=d1.CLOSE AND mindate=d1.DATEX
  JOIN datos_5minutos d2
  ON c1.TIKER=d2.TIKER AND c1.CLOSE=d2.CLOSE AND maxdate=d2.DATEX;
```

Para el dataset de ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE datos_5minutos(
  ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  TIKER varchar(15),
  DATEX datetime,
  CLOSE varchar(15),
  VOLUME float
  );
INSERT INTO datos_5minutos (TIKER,DATEX,CLOSE,VOLUME) VALUES
  (1,'2020-03-10','OPEN',1),
  (1,'2020-03-11','OPEN',2),
  (1,'2020-03-12','HIGH',3),
  (1,'2020-03-13','HIGH',4),
  (1,'2020-03-12','LOW',5),
  (1,'2020-03-13','LOW',6),
  (1,'2020-03-14','CLOSE',7),
  (1,'2020-03-15','CLOSE',8),
  (2,'2020-03-10','OPEN',11),
  (2,'2020-03-11','OPEN',12),
  (2,'2020-03-12','HIGH',13),
  (2,'2020-03-13','HIGH',14),
  (2,'2020-03-12','LOW',15),
  (2,'2020-03-13','LOW',16),
  (2,'2020-03-14','CLOSE',17),
  (2,'2020-03-15','CLOSE',18);
```

Se obtienen estos resultados:

> ```
> =====================================================================
> |  TIKER   |  CLOSE   | maxdate  | mindate  |mindate_vol|maxdate_vol|
> =====================================================================
> |    1     |   OPEN   |11/03/2020|10/03/2020|    1,0    |    2,0    |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------
> |    1     |   HIGH   |13/03/2020|12/03/2020|    3,0    |    4,0    |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------
> |    1     |   LOW    |13/03/2020|12/03/2020|    5,0    |    6,0    |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------
> |    1     |  CLOSE   |15/03/2020|14/03/2020|    7,0    |    8,0    |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------
> |    2     |   OPEN   |11/03/2020|10/03/2020|    11,0   |    12,0   |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------
> |    2     |   HIGH   |13/03/2020|12/03/2020|    13,0   |    14,0   |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------
> |    2     |   LOW    |13/03/2020|12/03/2020|    15,0   |    16,0   |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------
> |    2     |  CLOSE   |15/03/2020|14/03/2020|    17,0   |    18,0   |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Por favor, confírmame si he interpretado bien tus instrucciones. A través de comentarios o ampliando tu pregunta con la salida que te gustaría obtener

Comment: Buenas tardes amigo David, le agredezco mucho su tiempo para ayudarme con eso. En este momento estoy haciendo un recopilado para explicarme mas claramente

Comment: Perfecto, estamos en contacto. Modifica tu pregunta para que yo pueda modificar mi respuesta.